# Spectrum calculate.

Tags: functional-analysis

$T:\ell_2(\mathbb {Z}) \to \ell_2(\mathbb {Z});
\\ T(..., x_{-2}, x_{-1}, (x_0), x_1, x_2, \dotsc)=(..., 2x_{-4}, 2x_{-3}, 2x_{-2} + 3x_0, (3x_{-1}), x_0, x_1, x_2, \dotsc).$

Element in round brackets at the position zero in the sequence of coordinates.

I need to find the spectrum. For now I know the point spectrum, it is $\{\lambda | 1 < |\lambda| < 2\} \cup \{-3, 3\}$ (these are those $\lambda$, such that ($\lambda * I - T)$ is not injective). I need  help to find all lambda such that $\lambda - I * T$ is surjective. 
If there is another approach to this problem, it also will be very helpful.

Comment: Perhaps it might help to write $T = SU+R$, where $U$ is the left-shift, $R((x_n)) = 3x_0e_{-1}$ is a rank one operator, and $S$ is a multiplication operator given by a sequence in $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z})$.